# How to minify AngularAMD code?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, requirejs, angular-amd

I've been looking at the [AngularAMD library](https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD) and I'm wondering if there's a way to minify the code for use in production.

I've taken a look at the [AngularAMD sample](https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD-sample) which does have a Grunt configuration, but unfortunately, the instructions for building aren't working for me, and it's giving an error on the `grunt setup` step. So I'm not able to see whether this project is producing the sort of minimized code that I'm looking for.

When trying to use `grunt-contrib-concat` on the [example AngularAMD](http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/#/home) code, the problems I run into are the same ones that you traditionally run into when trying to minimize Angular projects with RequireJS which led to [Ravi Kiran's blog post](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-requirejs-angularjs-applications/) on how to integrate the two.

(e.g. defining both `app` which creates the initial Angular module, and its controllers as RequireJS modules ends up with a circular dependency, so that you need to define the controllers as individual functions, list those functions as dependencies in the code which creates the Angular module, and then call `angular.module(...).controller` on each of them.)

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with angularAMD-sample project during `grunt setup` resulting in cryptic `Fatal error: Arguments to path.join must be strings` was actually caused by an older version of `grunt-bower-task`.  Updating it to `0.4.0` from `0.3.2` resolved the problem.

`grunt deploy` should now produce the minified code with `angularAMD`.